# How to run projects containing jni folder in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, java-native-interface

I downloaded a project using `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git` and tried to run it in Android studio. But gradle is not working with it. My project structure:

[image]

`mosaic` and `mosaic_renderer` contain .h and .cpp files. The `gen` folder is currently empty.

I downloaded LLDB, CMake and NDK from the SDK manager. But still I can't run the project and the color on the java files means something is wrong.

I am relatively new to Android and I am getting confused about what to do now to run this project in Android studio.